# Separate instruction memory for each multiprocessor core

Tags: multiprocessing, vhdl, multiprocess

For a uni project, I'm required to implement a multiprocessor (build from single cycle core). I'm thinking of instantiating the single core processors inside the testbench, and then test for concurrency problem. However, since they're instantiated I can't change the instruction memory for each individual core, as changing one will change the others too. For this reason, I want to pull out the instruction memory, and create a new one for each core, then connect them to the cores in testbench. Can anyone give me some tips or whether it's possible to do so? I

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I understand that you've probably been working on this project some time, so you know all the ins and outs. However, we really need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Everything you describe should be possible. What are you allowed to modify for the project? How is the instr mem connected to the core? How do you "pull out" and "create" a that instr mem?

Comment: No. Each core will have its own copy of the instruction memory. What you need to do is load each copy with its own program, for example by passing a filename to the instance as a generic, and initialising the memory from the contents of that file.

Comment: I'm thinking instead of passing result from PC straight to instruction memory, I will pass it to testbench, then pass into insn_mem_core1 and then pass result instruction back into the single cycle core. I tried to implement it but when I tried running ModelSim, it says no design loaded